# Pull data from remote SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, xaml

I am new to XAML and I am looking for a sample/tutorial on how to pull data from a remote SQL Server for a Windows Store App. (8.1).

I did search thoroughly and I found a local DB example on MSDN but only with JavaScript and was unable to find a C# version.

Can someone please assist with some links. Thanks in advance.

Comment: a very good start : http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlcommand

Comment: That is fine for normal winforms apps but I need help with a Windows 8.1 Store App.

Comment: see https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-access-data-from-5f2602ec/sourcecode?fileId=106331&pathId=1504792740

Comment: Yup that's the one I found also but if you check it out they only provide javascript which no good for C#

Comment: How about you create a webapi, do the database handling there and then consume it in your windows app code. Worth a try.

Comment: Yes, it seems like WCF service is the only way thus far.

Comment: A webapi is more lightweight in terms, it serves you json. Or a REST service.